# Given an array of scores, return true if each score is equal or lesser than the one before. The array will be length 2 or more

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

What is the problem to my code? I have tried to do this peoblem, but I don't find a good solution. Please help me, if you can!?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int[] scores = new int[n];
    int c = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
        scores[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }

    for(int j = scores.length-1; j >= 0; j--){
        boolean b = scores[j] <= scores[j-1] ? true : false;
        if(b == false){
            c++;
        }
    }
    if(c > 0){
        System.out.print(false);
    }
```

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: what do you want to compare the index(0) with, when you do that it's being compared with index(-1) that's why you are getting an error.

Comment: I'm sorry I was really careless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could work when adding an `if statement` to check if `j > 0` so you won't get an exception when checking the 0 index with -1 index

```
 for(int j = scores.length-1; j >= 0; j--){
      if(j > 0) {
          boolean b = scores[j] <= scores[j-1] ? true : false;
          if(b == false){
           c++;
          }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Your code really works.I'm thankful!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

I really didn't understand your code, but this for loop would do what you need:

```
for(int i=0; i<scores.length-2; i++) {
    if(scores[i] > scores[i+1]) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Basically what we need to do here is to run on all of the elements in the array **except** the last element (which is in the place `scores.length-1`) because we will check the last element when we compare the second last element to it.
Once we have found 2 neighboring elements that doesn't satisfy the if condition there is no need to check further, we can return false right away.

If we have scanned ALL the elements and we didn't find any violation we can return true.

Comment: While I understand that you wish to be helpful, please try to avoid answering questions that are not up to the standard outlined in the [help].

Comment: @JoeC no reason for that minus 1. if he didn't ask his question properly shouldn't mean we don't need to help him. you can give him minus 1 for asking the question badly. but my answer is right on for his question. please reconsider as I take my reputation seriously.

Comment: The tooltip for the downvote is "This answer is not useful".  It is not useful to the OP in the long term as he has gained precisely zero knowledge from this (I reckon this is an assignment and he may simply copy and paste this code), and it is not useful to the community because it is a very narrow problem that is of no benefit to future visitors.

Comment: @JoeC This website is not only to answer general and broad questions. People have helped me in the past with some very specific stuff. I understand that this is probably his homework, and yet I think I should help him. Just for the benefit of the doubt, I took your comments and added an explanation to my code so he could understand it better and maybe develop the right mindset for solving the rest of him homework.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!